# Clustered key lookup high cost

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition (64-bit). Why is my query executing so slowly? It's taking 10 minutes.

Here are some screenshots of the execution plans which places cost most

[image]

[image]

```
SELECT 
    1_code
    ,count(DISTINCT 2_code) AS viso
FROM
    docum(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    for_vers(NOLOCK) ON doc = fv
INNER JOIN 
    for(NOLOCK) ON fv = f
INNER JOIN 
    persons(NOLOCK) ON doc = p
INNER JOIN 
    tax ti(NOLOCK) ON p = ti
INNER JOIN 
    person(NOLOCK) ON pm = p
WHERE 
    pm_ = 14
    AND (pm_date IS NULL OR pm_date > getdate())
    AND (pm_till IS NULL OR pm_till > getdate())
    AND start_date >= '2015-01-01'
    AND end_date <= '2015-12-31'
    AND code = 1
    AND code IN (25)
    AND dprt_code IN (20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 30)
GROUP BY
    code
```

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Product specific problem...)

Comment: How many rows does the `documents` table really have?

Comment: 52082116 rows have documents table

Comment: @ArveZ That's a way more than `estimated rows number` suggest in the execution plan. When did you update the statistics last time?

Comment: what statistics? i check now in my table, all info is from today

Comment: This looks like a financial type of application. Are you aware of what those NOLOCK hints are doing? It is NOT as simple as dirty reads. Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate rows? http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: We can't really help a lot with the performance other than really broad brush strokes unless we have table definition (including indexes) at the very least. An actual (not the estimated) execution plan would help. But I suspect that as @IvanSivak pointed out, your statistics are horribly out of date. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx

Comment: Your fattest arrows are around your joins... if you could denormalize some of your data it would probably help. Also, your two `field IS NULL OR ...` subclauses in the where clause are expensive. Get rid of those if you can. The NOLOCKs are likely not helping performance at all.

Comment: the actual execution plane is the same, here is indexes http://i.imgur.com/KKBRXVv.png

Comment: @Sean Lange and/or rows dont are duplicate

Comment: Did you look at the article I posted? Using NOLOCK you can and will get missing and/or duplicate rows at random times. It is not because there are duplicate rows in the table.

Comment: When I asked to post the actual execution plan it is not because I expect there to be differences. It is because the actual plan contains information vital to solving performance problems. Screen shots are useless. And posting a list of index names is also useless. That does not state what those indexes are. I am willing to help but you have to post some details so we can help.

Comment: Questions, Answers, belong, as well as any other content, to StackOverflow from the second on that they're posted. So please, don't vandalize your own content. If you want to no longer be associated with a question/answer, use the "contact us"-link & ask for a disassociation.

Answer (score 2):

Consider updating the `statistics`. Your execution plan shows a big difference between actual rows number (as you claim *52,082,116* rows) and the estimated rows number shown by execution plan. To find out more about statistics see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397.aspx). To quote:

> The query optimizer uses statistics to create query plans that improve
>   query performance.

You can call the `update statistics` query as mentioned in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) but please keep in mind when and where you run this command (it will affect the performance). Be carefull and read the docs. Consider perhaps the `Update Statistics Task` in the [Maintenance Plan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178678.aspx). There's also a nice [article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/importance-of-statistics-and-how-it-works-in-sql-server-part-1.html) which explains more about statistics and performance.

As others pointed out in the comments, consider some sort of [Denormalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505841.aspx) and double check if your [isolation level](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is really alright (your `nolock`).

Check these [hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647793.aspx#scalenetchapt14%20_topic11) for understanding the execution plan.

Comment: @ArveZ Depends. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397.aspx#UpdateStatistics the thing is that estimated numbers vs. real numbers differs a lot and as such query optimizer might not choose the best query plan.

Comment: /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [sys].[sp_updatestats]    Script Date: 02/25/2016 17:02:01 ******/

Answer (score 1):

If possible then try to reduce those inner joins. If not possible then try to inner join at the end of the script. It saves huge time.

And for removing Clustered key lookup you should use **Covering Index**. If you properly create **Covering Index** then there will be no ***Clustered key lookup***.